# How to exit properly a Queue and Qthread for tests with pytest?

Tags: python, pyqt, pytest, python-multiprocessing, qthread

I created a GUI with `PyQt5`, and I wand to test it through `pytest`.

I my GUI requires to redirect the standard output, so I use a `Qthread` to create a listener.
This listener put the `stdout` in a `Queue` and send a signal which exploited by the GUI.

Until here, there is no problem. My issue appears when I what to quit; when I quit using python interpreter I have no problem, but when I use `pytest` I get `EOFError` or a message saying that I kill a running thread. 
I tried to quit correctly but the problem persist, so I came for help.

Here is an example of the `GUI.py` :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from functools import partial
import multiprocessing
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtTest

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QTextCursor


class MyReceiver(QObject):
    mysignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,queue,*args,**kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.queue = queue
        self.runCondition=True

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def run(self):
        while self.runCondition:
            text = self.queue.get()
            self.mysignal.emit(text)

def QueueStreamSetup():

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)

    sys.stdout = WriteStream(queue)
    #sys.stderr = WriteStream(queue)

    return queue

class WriteStream(object):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def write(self, text):
        self.queue.put(text)

    def flush(self):
        self.queue.put('FLUSH ')
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(2 * 1000)
        pass

def threadConnect(view, queue):
    qthread = QThread()
    my_receiver = MyReceiver(queue)

    my_receiver.mysignal.connect(view.append_text)
    my_receiver.moveToThread(qthread)
    #
    qthread.started.connect(partial(my_receiver.run,))

    qthread.start()
    return(qthread, my_receiver)


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(self)

    def restore(self):
        # Restore sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def append_text(self,text):
        self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText( text )
        self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)

    def initUI(self, MainWindow):
        # centralwidget
        MainWindow.resize(346, 193)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        # The Action to quit
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        # The bar
        self.statusBar()
        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.menubar.addMenu('&File')
        self.exitMenu=self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)

        # tThe Button
        self.btn_quit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_quit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 89, 25))
        self.btn_quit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.doPrint() )

        # The textEdit
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 321, 81))

        # Show the frame
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()

    def doPrint(self):
        # Test to print something.
        print('TEST doPrint')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Ask a question before to quit.
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
            QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        # Treat the answer.
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.restore()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

def main():
    queue = QueueStreamSetup()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    qthread, my_receiver = threadConnect(ex, queue)

    return app, ex, queue, qthread, my_receiver

def finish(queue, qthread, my_receiver):
    print('Finish')
    my_receiver.runCondition=False
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
    qthread.terminate()
    qthread.wait()
    qthread.exit()
    print('Finish Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app, ex, queue, qthread, my_receiver =main()
    rc= app.exec_()
    finish(queue, qthread, my_receiver)

    print('the application ends with exit code {}'.format(rc))
    sys.exit(rc)
```

Then the pytest file named test_GUI.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
import pytest

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtTest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QObject

import GUI

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def Viewer(request):
    print("  SETUP GUI")
    yield GUI.main()
    print("  TEARDOWN GUI")

class Test_GUI_CXS() :

    def test_launching(self, Viewer, qtbot, mocker, caplog):
        # open the window and add the qtbot.
        print("  SETUP Window")
        app, window, queue, qthread, my_receiver = Viewer
        qtbot.addWidget(window)
        qtbot.wait_for_window_shown(window)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(0.5 *1000)

        # Test
        qtbot.mouseClick( window.btn_quit, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton )
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(0.5 *1000)

        # EXIT
        mocker.patch.object(QMessageBox, 'question', return_value=QMessageBox.Yes)
        window.exitAction.trigger()
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1 *1000)
        assert window.close()

        # Finish the processes.
        print( "App END")
        GUI.finish(queue, qthread, my_receiver)
        print( "END TEST.")
```

So if I run the command: `pytest -v -s ./test_GUI.py` , I get the following element in the messages:

```
Qt exceptions in virtual methods:
________________________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx/GUI.py", line 25, in run
   text = self.queue.get()

File "xxx/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

I do not understand why there is this end of file error, but I assume that it is linked with the termination of the `Queue` and the `Qthread`. 
Because until the `Queue` is not empty, the `my_receiver` can not stop running and so the `Qthread` can not be terminate.
Unfortunately I found nothing about this kind of problem on the Internet.

Any suggestions or help on this case would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you close the Queue the `self.queue.get()` is still running, preventing the thread from finishing executing as it blocks `while self.runCondition:` from executing. Considering the above a possible solution is to send a None and then just close the Queue:

```
class MyReceiver(QObject):
    mysignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, queue, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyReceiver, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = queue
        self.runCondition = True

    def run(self):
        while self.runCondition:
            text = self.queue.get()
            if isinstance(text, str):
                self.mysignal.emit(text)
```

```
def finish(queue, qthread, my_receiver):
    print('Finish')
    my_receiver.runCondition = False
    queue.put(None)
    qthread.quit()
    qthread.wait()
    qthread.exit()
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
    print('Finish Done')
```

Comment: Your solution seems very good. Nevertheless I have one remark.
Now when you run the GUI (not the pytest) you get the following warning:´Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must not let any exception whatsoever propagate through Qt code. If that is not possible, in Qt 5 you must at least reimplement QCoreApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.´
What do you think about it ?

Comment: Also do you have any idea why, it is still working on my bigger project. I think this still related to the termination of the process, since I get the following message:´Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread yyyyy (most recent call first):
  File "xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytestqt/qtbot.py", line 675 in _close_widgets´

So it seems like there is a problem with the closing of a widget but I don't understand why.

Comment: @R.N mmm, how strange. I don't get those mistakes. Could you tell me what your development environment is, ie python version, OS, PyQt5 version, etc.

Comment: Currently I work with a Ubuntu18.04, with conda 4.7.12, python 3.7.5, pyqt 5.9.2, pytest 5.2.4, pytest-qt 3.2.2, qt 5.9.7

Comment: I found my mistake. Your answer use correctly the method `quit()` rather than `terminate()` which was responsible of the `Qt notify`. The second error is still obscure to me but is related to the organisation to the `fixture` of `pytest`.